# DAX for power bi measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a relational model of 3 tables built in power bi that flows downstream this way:

Operator > Location > Transaction

Operators have a primary key that could match to multiple locations. Locations have a primary key that could match with multiple transactions.

I get monthly data on these transactions and in some months an operator or location may not have any related transactions. I'm trying to create two measures, one that gives a total number of unique locations where a transaction occurred and one that gives a total number of unique operators that participated in a transaction. I don't want to eliminate any entries from the operator or location tables because some operators and locations only have semi-regular monthly transactions.

My mind is only thinking about it as filtering upstream instead of downstream, but I want to avoid creating a bi-directional relationship for any of my tables. I'm not sure how to create a measure with DAX to get what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question, add some dummy data and your desired output;
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302472/14366538

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.